# Kafka streams suppress does not return any values

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Im struggling on a relatively simple Windowed Word Count example.
I'm trying to get only the windowed results but does not receive anything at all.

```
KStream<String, Long> sl = s
    ...
    .groupBy((key, value) -> value)
    .windowedBy(of(ofSeconds(5))
        .advanceBy(ofSeconds(3))
        .grace(ofSeconds(2)))
    .count(Materialized.<String, Long, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(
        "counts-store").withRetention(ofSeconds(7)))
    .suppress(untilWindowCloses(unbounded()))
    .toStream()
    .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(key.key(), value))
    .to(outputTopicName, produced);
```

I'm piping in some input:

```
inputWords.pipeInput(new TestRecord<>("word", "a b c", now));
inputWords.pipeInput(new TestRecord<>("word", "a c d c", now.plus(ofSeconds(6))));
inputWords.pipeInput(new TestRecord<>("word", "", now.plus(Duration.ofDays(1))));
```

But nothing gets emitted.
Someone knows a possible solution?

As you can see i'm already using grace and retention, as others wrote this could help but it's actually not helping.
On commenting suppress line everything works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide valid `Serdes` for your count `Materialized` view so Kafka Stream can correctly provide valid Window Serdes for internal suppress processor, if not then this processor will pick default key serdes which may lead to serialization not work correctly, I get following Exception in `KTableSuppressProcessor.buffer()`:

```
//please check if you get this exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed cannot be cast to java.lang.String

    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:28)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.suppress.KTableSuppressProcessor.buffer(KTableSuppressProcessor.java:86)
```

Correctly provide valid `Serde` for Materialized view `counts-store` and you should get expected output:

```
Materialized.<String, Long, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("counts-store")
    .withRetention(ofSeconds(7))
    .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
    .withValueSerde(Serdes.Long())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually i didn't get **any** error messages but this fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @PatrickSchubert what kind of log config you are using? Also I forgot to mention that if you using suppress, the current suppressed window only gets un-suppressed if you have new messages in the next new window

Comment: I wasn't using any specific own config. Just used the maven archetype from the tutorial (https://kafka.apache.org/24/documentation/streams/tutorial). I'm not trying to dive deeper into Kafka Streams. Was just scratching the surface of Kafka Streams for my Master's Thesis. Thanks a lot for your help.
PS: I'd like to upvote your Answers but sadly i can't do it with my reputation.